# Insertar elemento al final de una lista en Python

Tags: python-2.7, lista

el caso es que no se como insertar un elemento al final, siempre queda insertado en penúltimo lugar.

```
lista = [5, 1, 2, 4, 25, 6, 8]
lista2 = []

for num in lista:
    lista2.append(num)


#Aquí quiero coger el elemento más pequeño y ponerlo al final de mi lista, 
#para ello primero lo inserto y después elimino el duplicado.
lista2.insert(-1, min(lista))
lista2.remove(min(lista))


print lista2
```

Este sería el resultado del código:

[5, 2, 4, 25, 6, 1, 8]

Comment: si lo que quieres es poner el minimo elemento al final..pq no usas `lista2.append(min(lista))` en lugar de `lista2.insert(-1, min(lista))`?

Comment: No, dentro del bucle for no. te digo que sustituyas despues del bucle `lista2.insert(-1, min(lista))` por `lista2.append(min(lista))`. Mira mi respuesta

Comment: Vale correcto, no sabía que el append te añadía el elemento al final, creía que lo hacía de forma aleatoria. Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es insertar un elemento al final, tienes varias opciones. Puedes usar `append`que automáticamente añade el elemento al final de la lista sin tener que especificar un indice:

```
lista2.append(min(lista))
```

o si no, puedes usar `insert`, pero pasando como indice a insertar la longitud de la lista:

```
lista2.insert(len(lista2), min(lista))
```

Cuando usas un numero negativo como indice, lo que haces es "contar desde el final". Pero como usas -1, lo que haces es contar 1 desde el último elemento, y por eso te lo inserta en la posición anterior a la última.

De todas maneras, tu código funcionará porque insertas el elemento menor al final y luego quitas el mínimo, que estará situado antes. Pero si por ejemplo, quisieras insertar el menor elemento al principio, no te funcionaría. Lo normal es que guardaras el elemento en una variable, lo eliminaras de la lista, y lo insertaras despues:

```
lista = [5, 1, 2, 4, 25, 6, 8]
lista2 = []

for num in lista:
    lista2.append(num)


elemento = min(lista)
lista2.remove(elemento)
lista2.append(elemento)
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, aún soy cinturón blanco en esto.

Answer (score 0):

La solución estaría en sustituir lista2.insert(-1, min(lista)) por lista2.append(min(lista)), ya que el comando .append agrega los elementos siempre al final. Quedaría así el código.

```
lista = [5, 1, 2, 4, 25, 6, 8] 
lista2 = []

for num in lista:
    lista2.append(num)

lista2.append(min(lista)) 
lista2.remove(min(lista))


print lista2
```